# How to convert a response to full json format

Tags: node.js

I have the next response:

```
{
  "Status": 200,
  "Email": "aristos@gmail.com",
  "Values": "[\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"John\\\",\\\"age\\\":30,\\\"ids\\\":[ \\\"123445\\\", \\\"2345456\\\", \\\"42346\\\" ]}\"]"
}
```

I want to fix this part:

```
  "Values": "[\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"John\\\",\\\"age\\\":30,\\\"ids\\\":[ \\\"123445\\\", \\\"2345456\\\", \\\"42346\\\" ]}\"]"
```

So it looks better like this:

```
{ Status: 200,
  Email: 'aristos@gmail.com',
  Values:  '{"name":"John","age":30,"ids":[ "123445", "2345456", "42346" ]}'  }
```

I'm using node js.

```
    var result={Status: 200,
        Email: req.body.email,
      Values: req.body.values};
```

The request is :

```
email:aristos@gmail.com
values:{"name":"John","age":30,"ids":[ "123445", "2345456", "42346" ]}
```

a post call

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use `req.body.values` is better to use the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method like this:

```
var val = JSON.parse(req.body.values);
```

And then your final response String should be stringify using the [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method:

```
var result={Status: 200,
            Email: "email@example.com",
            Values: val};      
const response = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Please take a look of this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nddbx953/).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your data is wrapped into array and stringified, but that's another story.

So, you need to parse a json string, and get 1st array element. Like this:

```js
const response = {
  "Status": 200,
  "Email": "aristos@gmail.com",
  "Values": "[\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"John\\\",\\\"age\\\":30,\\\"ids\\\":[ \\\"123445\\\", \\\"2345456\\\", \\\"42346\\\" ]}\"]"
};

// now it's parsed and unescaped like - {"name":"John","age":30,"ids":[ "123445", "2345456", "42346" ]}
const values = JSON.parse(response.Values)[0];

response.Values = values;

// From now 'response' object will be as you want
```